# For $0 \le x\le 1 $ , $0\le y \le 1$ and $x+y = 1$ what is the range of $1-x^2-y^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Assume $0 \le x\le 1$ , $0 \le y \le 1$ and $x+y = 1$ I'm looking for the range of $1-x^2-y^2$

I could solve this problem with this apparoach:

$$x+ y = 1 \Rightarrow y = 1- x$$
$$1-x^2-y^2 = 1-x^2-(x-1)^2 = -2x^2+2x= -2x(x-1)$$And It is easy to see the range is $[0,\frac12]$ (for example by drawing the graph of the funciton).

But I'm wondering if it is possible to solve this problem with multi-variable calculus. For this purpose I considered the surface $z = 1-x^2-y^2$ and the plane $x+y = 1$ and we are looking for the range of their intersection. I can visualize that the intersection of this paraboloid and the plane $x + y = 1$ contain two points $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ So the minimum of the function $1-x^2-y^2$ is zero. But I'm wondering how to find the maximum by this approach? Also is it possible to solve it algebraically by using multi-variable calculus techniques?

Comment: Using calculus, you want to find the extrema of $f(x,y)=1-x^2-y^2$ subject to $x+y=1$. Plug the constraint in to reduce it max/minimizing $g(x)=f(x,1-x)=2x-2x^2$. You can use [derivative tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test). Use the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for the multivariable approach.

Comment: you want to solve the problem only with multivaiable calculus?

Comment: @NN2 Yes, I'm curious to see if it is possible to solve it with multivaiable calculus approaches.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved with its geometric meaning(maybe it's similar to a multi-variable calculus).

Mentioned that $0\leq x,y \leq 1, x+y=1$ represent a segment of a line(in this graph it is AB):
[image: The graph of the line]

To find the range of $1-x^2-y^2$, we can firstly find the range of $x^2+y^2$.

In the graph, it means a circle with the center $(0,0)$, and we need to find the range of its radius R.

To satisfy the conditions above, there exist an insection between this circle and the line.

So the problem converges to this problem:

> Given a line $x+y=1,0\leq x,y \leq 1$ and circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$, if there exist an insection between the circle and the line, find the range of R.

Maximum:

Easily we found that when this circle passes $A(0,1), B(1,0)$, the radium of the circle can take the maximum value $R=1$.

[image: Maximum of R]

Minimum:

When the line is tangent to the circle, we can get the minimum of R, which is $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

(This can be caculate by this way: in the graph we have $R=OT$, then in $Rt\Delta OTA$ we have $OT^2= OA^2-(\frac{AB}{2})^2=\frac{1}{2}$)

[image: Minimum of R]

Then we knows that $R\in [\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, 1],x^2+y^2=R^2\in [\frac{1}{2},1], 1-x^2-y^2\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.